# Android TimePickerDialog set time issue (Lollipop 5.0.1 on Samsung Note4)

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, samsung-mobile, android-timepicker

I'm having a weird behavior. I've created a custom `TimePickerDialog` to handle custom minute intervals (5, 10, 15) to display on the minute spinner.

The problem is that now, on Note 4 with Lollipop 5.0.1 I'm facing a strange problem:
If I try to set the time with the keyboard, the numbers on the minute spinner disappears and I cannot enter any value; on the hour spinner there is no problem instead.

On the logcat, when I click on the minute spinner, I'm having these two warnings (maybe related):

```
09-15 10:18:26.790: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19382): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
09-15 10:18:26.790: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(19382): getCursorCapsMode on inactive InputConnection
```

This is my code for the custom `TimePickerDialog.onAttachedToWindow()` method:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    try {
        Class<?> classForid = Class.forName("com.android.internal.R$id");
        Field timePickerField = classForid.getField("timePicker");
        this.timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(timePickerField.getInt(null));
        Field field = classForid.getField("minute");

        NumberPicker mMinuteSpinner = (NumberPicker) timePicker.findViewById(field.getInt(null));
        mMinuteSpinner.setMinValue(0);
        mMinuteSpinner.setMaxValue((60 / time_interval) - 1);
//          List<String> displayedValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i += time_interval) {
            displayedValues.add(String.format("%02d", i));
        }
        mMinuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues.toArray(new String[0]));

        Field numberpickerField = classForid.getField("numberpicker_input");
        EditText mInputText = (EditText) mMinuteSpinner.findViewById(numberpickerField.getInt(null));
        mInputText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

**On Android 5.0.1, on Samsung Note4 at least**, in my case there is a problem with the values passed to the timePicker.

```
mMinuteSpinner.setDisplayedValues(displayedValues.toArray(new String[0]));
```

The values passed to `setDisplayValues()` need to be normal numbers `{"0","1","2","3"..}` and not 2digit numbers `{"00", "01", "02"..}`to work properly.

Just for laughing a little bit more...

**Lollipop 5.1.1, tested again on Note4, doesn't have this strange behaviour**

Hope to have been useful for someone.
Cheers